# How to reveal dynamic data on click with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, dynamic

**EDIT**: [**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52049075/how-to-dynamically-reveal-json-data-on-click-from-an-api/52049490?noredirect=1#comment91050233_52049490) is a more sound approach, since provided answer may have bugs when implementing `a` tags, or `img` tags.

================================================================

I am calling blog data from an API. (I've reformatted the data into an array by month).

So far, the blog titles print to the web page. I'd like a user to be able to click a title and have its description revealed.

Here is some of my code so far:

```
var blogPosts = $('#blog-posts');

    $.each(byMonth, function(key, value) {
      var outer = byMonth[key]

      $.each(outer, function(k, v) {
        var inner = outer[k]

        var monthBlogPosts = $('<div class = "month"> </div>').appendTo(blogPosts);

        $.each(inner, function(i, obj) {

          title = inner[i].Title
          description = inner[i].Description
          date = inner[i].DatePublished

          $('<div class = "title-list"><h3 class = "unique-title">' + title + '</h3></div>').appendTo(monthBlogPosts)

          // if a title is clicked, show its Description
          showDescription(description);

        })
      })
    });

    function showDescription(d){
      $('.unique-title').on('click', function(){
        $('<p>' + d + '</p>').appendTo('body')
        console.log(d)
      })
    }
```

When I click a title, all descriptions print instead of the matching description. I understand this is because I called the function in a nested loop, but I've also had trouble calling the description variable outside of it.

I have also tried

```
showDescription(title, description)

//...

function showDescription(t, d){
      $(title).on('click', function(){
        $('<p>' + d + '</p>').appendTo('body')
        console.log(d)
      })
    }
```

but then nothing is printed to the html page.

Essentially, I'd like to grab the title index, and print it's respective description when its clicked.

Comment: You are calling showDescription multiple times.  And you are doing a global selector on the `.unique-title`.  This is going to be creating duplicate bindings which is going to result in undesired behavior in your application.  Only bind once.

Comment: You are appending a new `p` tag any time the title is clicked.  Is this intended, or should there be at most one description displayed at any given time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use event delegation to attach a click event to the document that will bubble up and trigger when `.title-list` is the event target.

```
$(document).on('click', '.title-list', function(event) { 
    showDescription(event.currentTarget) // pass the element being clicked (we will need it later)
})
```

you would also need to modify the way you get the description.
you could store you description in a data attribute of `.title-list` like so:

```
$('<div class = "title-list" data-description="'+ description  +'"><h3 class = "unique-title">' + title + '</h3></div>').appendTo(monthBlogPosts)
```

so you can now modify `showDescription()` so it would get the data from the element we pass to the function

```
function showDescription(element){
    var d = $(element).data('description')
    $('<p>' + d + '</p>').appendTo('body')
    console.log(d)
  })
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution works. I had to make a minor edit from document.on to $(document).on

Comment: @miranda Just a note. Instead of `$(document)` you can use closest available parent. With closest available parent,  browser doesn't have to traverse through all the dom elements to reach till document. I am guess `$('#blog-posts').on....` should work and should be faster.

Comment: corrected my mistake on $(document), and yes the event should be attached to a common parent, preferably not document

Answer (score 1):

So ok. From whatever I could understand (by looking at your code). You cannot register an event with simple `on` for dynamically added element. You have to use on delegate.

Try this

1) remove the function call (inside a loop)

2) delete the entire function `showDescription` and add event as below:

```
 $('#blog-posts').on('click', '.unique-title',function(){
     alert('title clicked').
 });
```

3) As to display the description I think the best way will be to add the description in a div and hide it. Display it later once the title is clicked.

```
 (inside the loop)
 $('<div class = "desc" style="display:none">' + description + '</div>').appendTo(monthBlogPosts);
```

then on #2 above. Replace with this.

```
$('#blog-posts').on('click', '.unique-title',function(){
    $(this).next('.desc').show(); //I am assuming desc will be next to the clicked title here. You can modify it as needed.
});
```

Finally, this is just an overview of a code so might not work as expected but I am pretty sure this should give you an idea and get you started

Comment: The logic to this solution definitely makes sense. I think a $(document).ready is needed to make the show/hide functions work, which I didn't have.