# How to dynamically reveal JSON data on click from an API?

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax, api

I have data from a Tumblr API that I've successfully parsed, until I introduced `tags` within the body description. (This includes images, hyperlinks, etc)

What I'm essentially doing is creating a list of blog titles. A blog description is dynamically revealed depending on which title is clicked. I feel that this code breaks because of an issue with quotations, but I'm not sure how to work around this.

**[HERE IS A CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/designbymiranda/pen/eLzOrO)** demonstrating the issue with full code.

This is just a **partial** look at the error:

```
      //...
      $.each(inner, function(i, obj) {

          title = inner[i].Title
          description = inner[i].Description

     // Source of the error
     // data-description includes an <a> tag that breaks the code
          $('<div class = "title-list" data-title = "<h3>' + title + '</h3>" data-description="' + description  + '">' + title + '</div>').appendTo(monthblogList)

        })
      })
    });

    function showBlogEntry(element){
      var t = $(element).data('title')
      var ds = $(element).data('description')

      blogEntry.empty()

      $(t).appendTo(blogEntry)
      $(ds).appendTo(blogEntry)
    }
}
```

Again, I would recommend looking at [**CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/designbymiranda/pen/eLzOrO) to get a better understanding. I've included an `a` tag on the first blog post, to show the issue. [Here](https://a-dbm-blog.tumblr.com/post/177458897478/hipsum-no-1) is original the blog post.

Here is one solution I thought of:

```
if ($(description).has("a")) {
  // do something
}
```

But still unsure of how to fix the issue.

I need to grab information from the `title` and `description` variables and have it's data revealed on click depending on which title the user clicks. This was one solution, though it may not be the best. If there are other solutions aside from `data` tags, that would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing the data in the "data-" attribute of the HTMLDivElement, just keep a reference to JSON response from the API in your javascript and store an **index** or **id** in the "data-" attribute (possibly "data-post-id")

```
var blogData = [{Title: .., Description: ...}, ...]; //Data from JSON Response

...
...

$('<div class = "title-list" data-post-id =' + postId +'>' + title + '</div>').appendTo(monthblogList);

...
...    

function showBlogEntry(element){
      var id = $(element).data('post-id')
      var close = $('<span id = close> x </span>')

      blogEntry.empty()

      $(close).appendTo(blogEntry)
      $('<h3>' + blogData[id].Title + '</h3>').appendTo(blogEntry)
      $(blogData[id].Description).appendTo(blogEntry)

      $("#close").on("click", function (event) {
        blogEntry.empty()
        about.fadeIn()
      });
    }
```

Comment: The logic of this makes sense, but when I apply it it's still a little buggy. I may not be defining postId correctly, could you try explaining this a little more? Or perhaps demonstrating on codepen/jfiddle? Edit: the variable jData in my CodePen is considered the blogData

Comment: https://codepen.io/jmdejno/pen/MqeymL. I added 'var postData' to the top of the JS file and then cached the value for later use in 'showBlogEntry' while placing the id (or, in this case, the array index) in 'data-post-id'

Comment: Thank you! After looking it over it makes much more sense. Kudos